# GIT deleted file still submitted

Tags: git, github, heroku

I was making the process to update my Heroku APP via Github from my local folder

When reaching `git push origin master`I got an error because a json file was too big. So I manually deleted the file from the folder.

Then I did:

```
git add -A
git commit - m
git push origin master
```

And got again the same message as if the file was not deleted.

If I run `git status` I get `Your branch is ahead of origin/master by 5 commits`

I found a lot of questions about this but couldn't get this working. A lot of solutions depends on updates in your local repo from the server, but in my case my local files are the last updated.

Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did your commit actually go through? e.g. `git commit -  m` should be `git commit -m 'deleted a file'`

Comment: First time, yes. Now I get ''Your branch is ahead...'' message when I do ''git commit -m''

Comment: You’re not pushing or it’s not successful. May you share the output of the push?